# Using Classes when Python Scripting for Maya

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, maya

I am working through  *Maya Programming with Python Cookbook* by Adrian Herbez and having trouble with an example (pg. 31) which creates a class which produces a user interface for making simple spheres in Maya. When I reproduce the code and run the script it loads but nothing happens in Maya. I was able to create user interfaces without using the class method previously so I am wondering if there is something wrong with the class code. My understanding of classes is a bit shaky but I can't find what could be wrong with it. I am using Atom and calling the script using 
`import(makeSpheres)` and `reload(makeSpheres)`.

Here is the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class SpheresClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = cmds.window(title="Make Spheres",widthHeight=(300,200))
        cmds.columnLayout()
        self.numSpheres = cmds.intField(minValue=1)
        cmds.button(label="Make some spheres", command=self.makeSpheres)
        cmds.showWindow(self.win)

    def makeSpheres(self, *args):
        number = cmds.intField(self.numSpheres,query=True,value=True)
        for i in range(0,number):
            cmds.polySphere()
            cmds.move(i*2.2,0,0)

        SpheresClass()
```

In Atom the `self.win`,`self.numSpheres` and `self.makeSpheres` is being highlighted in red but but the linter doesn't have any error messages.

Comment: **SOLVED** The error was that I had an indent before SpheresClass() so that's fixed now! Oh no what a terrible first question!

Comment: you're actually calling `SpheresClass` within the `makeSpheres` function in that class. Is that what you're intending to do?

Comment: Don't sweat it @3orange1red, welcome to Stack Overflow and Python in Maya! Feel free to post your solution as an answer and accept it. All the best to you :)

Comment: Thank you @meepzh I'll do that now :)

Comment: Yes that was what I was doing wrong, thanks @AnnaNevison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was calling the `SpheresClass` from within the `makeSpheres` function.